# OKX new websocket stream implementation through ccxt

Tags: python, ccxt

Since the subscription to the balance_and_position channel is not available, I try to implement that by taking reference to watch_balance() in the ccxt/python/ccxt/pro/okx.py.

The way I implement that:

```py
async def watch_balance_and_position(self, params={}):
    #Subscription to the Balance and position channel
    #param dict params: extra parameters specific to the okx api endpoint
    #returns dict: a balance structure https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#websocket-api-private-channel-positions-channel
    await self.load_markets()
    await self.authenticate()
    return await self.subscribe('private', 'balance_and_position', None, params)
```

It seems that I can subscribe to the channel because when I check the exchange's client. subscriptions, it shows the following:

```
{None: True,
'authenticated': {'event': 'login', 'msg': '', 'code': '0'},
'balance_and_position': True}
```

Also when I turned on the exchange verbose, it can show the responding message. However, when I try to await for the function for further processing, I can't receive any response.

How to fix that / correct way to subscribe to that new instance in order for me to get the returned response and further process that?

Python version: Python 3.9.13
ccxt.pro version: CCXT version 3.0.43 (output from print('CCXT version', ccxt.pro.version))
Exchange in interest: Okx

Thank you for your help